# how to fill in excel table from PHP

Tags: php, excel, spreadsheet, xlsx, xls

I need some library or good documentation of xlsx files for writing out xls files from website. all I need to do is fill in content into predefined and styled table. I have considered writing everything directly from php but could't get hang of merging cells and if I could it would be a hell writing code for changing any style into a document instead its much better if I have predefined file uploaded and then just fill in.
Please redirect me or help me find some proper documentation.
Project is in early stage and can consider switching to other language like Node.js if it makes this part super easy but trying to keep it low profile prefer using PHP so i'm open to all ideas.
Thanks in advance to everyone.
PS. this is my first question on stackoverflow

Comment: did you try to google "php excel"? first answer is nice.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly do a Google search before posting questions like this. But answering your question, **[PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)** is a nice place to start. Just go through their documentation.

Comment: I guess my question was not clear enough. it seems to me most of the time you would not need to completely generate excel file from scratch and just need to write data into predefined table, and it would be very simple to use. I wanted to know if such library existed.